# Golang creating resource-efficient emailer

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-lambda, serverless

I've made a simple scheduler in Go that is meant to be long-running and using channels, when the ticker's channel is ready, I poll my database for emails to be sent out, which sends the email to the send channel and when it is ready, the email is sent out. For now the tick interval is every 10 minutes. This scheduler connects to the pg database once on startup.

Example:

```
for {
    select {
     case <-s.ticker.C:
      // query db, sends each email to s.send channel. Could just send them
      // without the channel though.
      go poll()
     case email := s.send:
      send(email) // sends the email via some email service
    }
}
```

My question is if would it be more safe/efficient to use this Go program which connects to the database once, or setup a Lambda function as a cronjob every 10 minutes? I've never used Lambda, but I believe there would be a new database connection every time it is run, which also involves fetching credentials.

Cost-wise assume that it doesn't matter, I'm only curious as to which would be more safe/efficient. Any information is appreciated!

Comment: "Efficient" in what regard? What resource(s) are you looking to optimize for?

Comment: @Adrian I guess I'm indirectly asking that, specifically: are establishing new db connections more network-expensive than maintaining a connection? CPU needed to execute the short-lived lambda function rather than keep the long-running Go program (could experiment and answer this one myself)?

Comment: The CPU needed for a process running on a VM and the CPU needed for a Lambda function are so effectively different as to be incomparable; one is consuming the CPU of a VM, the other is consuming CPU time billed by the second. The network traffic to handshake a connection vs keep a connection alive are both negligible at infrastructure scale; keepalive vs reconnect is an application-level optimization but you're not talking about the same application doing one or the other so that comparison also seems irrelevant.

Comment: If you're comparing running something as a Lambda or as a process on a VM, the only salient difference is cost, but your question says explicitly that cost isn't the concern, so it's hard to tell what exactly you're trying to optimize for here.

Comment: If cost is the most important difference, then that's the answer and I'll take it. Thanks!